# Are public and private keys necessary in jwt?

Tags: jwt

I have some security issues with JWT. Here is the things :

- The first is to create a token with only a single key and use it to register and authenticate tokens - ( It's rule a lot of development using).
- The second is to use the private key and the public key with the private key for registration to create a new token and only use the public key for token verification. [Click here for see the image in the second rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMBAs.png)

So my question is which two ways are more secure? And is the second rule of security really necessary?
Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the metric for security as the number of parties that can sign a token, the public/private key set is "more secure".  However, when and how you use either of those depends on the situation and there are use cases for wanting a single key.

The asymmetric keys is necessary if you want to be able to have the ability to verify the person who had the secret key created the token.  In the symmetric key situation, that key is shared by all parties.

In terms of "security" as being able to decipher an encrypted message without the key, it depends on the algorithm used, either symmetric or asymmetric.